# Reading .txt file and organizing into two-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I'm looking to take a somewhat lengthy text file 50 rows  by 2 columns, have a user input the file name and read it into a two demensional array. The text file is a combination of organized names  (including commas) and numbers.
I can get the console to display the text file itself, but I'm stuck when it comes to orgazing the data into the array. I'm trying to devise a loop code involving `getline` and `find` in order for program through sort through the .txt, stop at a comma and record every character before that comma into a location (i.e [0] [0]) of the array. I'm aware that using vectors would be easier, but I'd like to solve this with an array.

Also, there is the issue of reading names (strings) into the array (int).

Comment: Show format of file. Also storing strings in place of int is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please test this code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

template<typename Out>
void split(const std::string &s, char delim, Out result) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.str(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        *(result++) = item;
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, std::back_inserter(elems));
    return elems;
}
int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("test.txt", std::ios::binary);
    std::string a, b;
    int c;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> arr;
    if (file)
    {
        while (file >> a )
        {
            std::vector<std::string> v = split(a, ',');
            arr.push_back(v);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

my test.txt:

```
m,2
n,4
o,6
p,8
q,10
```